# Java TrayIcon.displayMessage does not work after computer sleeps

Tags: java, multithreading, sleep, system-tray, trayicon

I have a class that does the following, though with a more constructive message:

```
class myClass extends Thread{
TrayIcon icon = new TrayIcon(SomeImage);
public myClass(){
    SystemTray tray = SystemTray.getSystemTray();
    tray.add(icon);
    }
public run(){
    final int seconds = 1000;
    try{
        while(true){
            icon.displayMessage("Some Title", "Some content", TrayIcon.MessageType.INFO);
            sleep(1800*seconds);
            }
        }
    catch(InterruptedException e){
         this.run();
         e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The class works and does what it is supposed to, showing some message to the user at a given interval.
My problem appears when the computer goes into sleep-mode. After it has been in sleep-mode for some time, say 3 hours, TrayIcon.displayMessage() stops working properly.

Messages that "should have" been displayed during sleep come sporadically and any new messages that are to be displayed will not be. The only solution I have found is to log off and back on to Windows, but I'd like to know if there's a less bothersome one.

Comment: Your wile look is dangerous, consider using some kind of `Timer` instead